# Error while injecting MockMvc with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, junit5

I'm trying to use mockmvc but it always shows the error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My class:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-cliente.properties")
public class ClienteRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    @Test
    public void simpleMockTest() throws Exception {
        var clienteMock = new Cliente("Jessica Pereira");
        Mockito.doReturn(Optional.of(clienteMock)).when(clienteService).buscar(2L);
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/clientes/pf/{id}", 1L))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

And my gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.rjdesenvolvimento'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.SR1')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1')
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    } '
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    testRuntime 'com.h2database:h2'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@AutoConfigureMockMvc should be used with `@SpringBootTest` or instead you can use `@WebMvcTest` to just load Spring MVC infrastructure for limited controller(s).

> Often, @WebMvcTest is limited to a single controller and is used in combination with @MockBean to provide mock implementations for required collaborators.
>
> @WebMvcTest also auto-configures MockMvc. Mock MVC offers a powerful way to quickly test MVC controllers without needing to start a full HTTP server.
>
> You can also auto-configure MockMvc in a non-@WebMvcTest (such as @SpringBootTest) by annotating it with @AutoConfigureMockMvc.

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests)

Comment: I have the @SpringBootTest annotation in mainTestClass, which spring creates by default.
With annotation in this class, it really does not work.

If I remove the annotation and put in each test class, it works.

Should not it work, even if the annotation is in mainTestClass?

Comment: No, spring create that empty test class as a placeholder. It's not correlated to any new test classes you write. There is no implicit inheritance.

Comment: I have both and still its giving the message

Answer (score 0):

Add this @AutoConfigureMockMvc to enable and configure auto-configuration of MockMvc